# IDA pro 7.5 - No previous fonts / color imports

Tags: ida, disassemblers

For the past few years I've been using an ida color scheme which I created, that was very easy on my eyes with the previous versions of **IDA Pro** (**<7.0**). However, after start using version **7.5** I cannot see any option to import colors from `.clr` files or export the current ones.

**IDA Pro 7.0**:

[image]

**IDA Pro 7.5**:

[image]

It seems to be a lot of font options are missing from the new version as well.

**IDA Pro 7.0 Fonts**:

[image]

**IDA Pro 7.5 Fonts**:

[image]

I don't have a lot of experience with IDA gui. I'd appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

I fixed the font problem by installing the desired font. However I still cannot figure out how to import `.clr` files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDA Pro dropped support for the `.clr` theme format in favour of CSS themes [upon the release of the 7.3 update](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/news/7_3/#regular-page). In order to port older `.clr` themes to the current format you can use a Python script that Hex-Rays provide [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/port_clr72_to_css.py).

e.g.
`port_clr72_to_css.py -i {theme}.clr > {theme}.css`
to produce a CSS formatted theme which can be placed in the relevant directory of your IDA 7.5 install: `$IDA_INSTALL/themes/{theme}/{theme}.css`.

Further documentation on the new themes can be found on [Hex-Rays site](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/themes/).